# What does the "?" key do in Java?

Tags: java

I've been trying to Google it, but googling the key "?" doesn't really work out that good.
I really want to know what it does and when to use it.

Thanks!

I've seen it a couple times, but here is an example of one I just saw

```
String name = perms.calculateRank().getColor() + player.getName();
//This is a custom ranking system ^
player.setPlayerListName(name.length() > 15 ? name.substring(0, 16) : name);
player.setDisplayName(name + ChatColor.RESET);
Chat.sendMessage(player, "Tab Name Set");
```

Comment: Posting the code that uses the symbol would help identify its meaning.

Comment: ? = ????? "Whats your question?"

Comment: I googled for "question mark operator java"---and guess what I found.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik OK, but if you're suggesting that the questioner should have just found their answer with Google--nothing in their question indicated that they knew it was called an "operator", and there are probably plenty of people out there who don't know that `?` is a "question mark".

Comment: @ajb If that's true, then I managed to teach OP three new things with four words :)

Answer (score 8):

This is a *ternary operator*.  In Java specifically, it is called the *[Conditional Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)*.  It is a way of writing short-hand simple `if..else` statements.  For example:

```
if (a == b) {
   c = 123;
} else {
   c = 456;
}
```

is the same as:

```
c = a == b ? 123 : 456;
```

Answer (score 7):

It is also used for a wildcard generic.

```
public List<?> getBizarreList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator `someBoolean ? x : y` evaluates to `x` if `someBoolean` is true, and `y` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It is called  **ternary operator** and it is only operator that takes `3` operands. In better sense, it is conditional operator that represent shorter format

**General Syntax** :

```
boolean expression ? value1 : value2
```

your example:

```
 player.setPlayerListName(name.length() > 15 ? name.substring(0, 16) : name);
```

as same as

```
  if( name.length() > 15)
    player.setPlayerListName(name.substring(0, 16));
  else
    player.setPlayerListName(name);
```